# How to push_back() number so they have a pair in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a grid/matrix which has even numbers of pairs (like in pairs for instance 1 would have another pair or 3 more 1's to make 2 pairs). Currently I have few with no pairs. How can I solve? Thanks.

I have done the coding for pushing, but I haven't succeeded yet to generate equal quantity of pairs.

```
 void initialize_grid() {

int rows = 6;
int columns = 6;
int numbers;
srand((unsigned int) time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    vector<int> row1; // game grid
    vector<int> row2; // hidden grid
    vector<int> row3; // guessed grid
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
        numbers = (rand() % 9) + 1;
        row1.push_back(numbers);
        row2.push_back(-1);
        row3.push_back(0);
    }
    game_grid.push_back(row1);
    hidden_grid.push_back(row2);
    guessed_grid.push_back(row3);       
}
cout << "Get ready, Challenger!" << endl << endl;
}

 /*Expected result (just an example) is something like this 
 2 6 3 1 0 4
 4 2 7 7 2 8
 4 7 3 2 5 1
 7 6 5 1 1 0
 8 4 6 0 0 6
 1 3 1 8 3 8*/
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: So sorry. I am trying to generate a grid that looks like the one in the expected result above. But I have few numbers that have no pair. Like 8 should have been 4 times in this grid, but it is there only three times. Or it should have been only two times.

Comment: ***8 should have been 4 times in this grid*** Why should it? Do you want to not have random numbers?

Comment: Your expected output does not seem to match what you are describing.

Comment: @Chora You are randomly generating numbers, there is no guarantee that they will be generated in pairs cause you make no provisions to do so.

Comment: If you want each number to appear a certain # of times you could put them into a vector and use std::shuffle

Comment: No no, it is just an example friends. This is just an example. I am trying to make a memory game with cards, where I let user pick rows and columns, if they guess matches in whole grid, then game gets over. But I am missing few match. Apology.

Comment: If you give an example it has to be a useful one that actually shows what you want to do. Otherwise what does it show? You should write, step by step, how you need your algorithm to work.

Comment: @drescherjm, I am sorry friend. I am bit new to programming. Could you show me how, if you don't mind. Please?

Comment: See the example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle instead of putting each # in the vector `v` 1 time put them in 2 times. Then loop through the vector to get your random numbers. This way every number will be in pairs.

Comment: @drescherjm, Thanks. I will look into it. Thanks all :) Sorry if I was little immature.

Comment: The difficulty was the way you asked the question. It was unclear what you want.

Comment: @drescherjm I actually I have no clue, even where to start, I added includes for algorithm and iterator. And trying to do shuffle(row1.begin(), row1.end(), [don't know what goes here) after row1. Could you give a mini example? Please!

Comment: Here is an example how to populate the random vector: https://ideone.com/kSwELr if you want to see how it works comment out the `shuffle()` and look at the output.

Comment: Once you have this random vector replace `(rand() % 9)` with `randVec[i++]` where i starts with 0. Get the random vector 1 time for your whole matrix and initialize i to 0 1 time as well before your 2 loops where you have `srand((unsigned int) time(0));`. I don't have time to post an answer I have to leave asap.

Comment: No problem boss. This actually helped me a lot. Don't have words to thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive what the rest of the code looks like, so I'm not sure what your goal is *exactly* with the hidden and guessed grids.  But if you want a a psudorandom grid below Get ready challenger this works:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int rows = 6;
int columns = 6;
int numbers;
    vector<vector<int>> game_grid, hidden_grid, guessed_grid;

srand((unsigned int) time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{   
    vector<int> row1; // game grid
    vector<int> row2; // hidden grid
    vector<int> row3; // guessed grid
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {   
        numbers = (rand() % 9) + 1;
        row1.push_back(numbers);
        row2.push_back(-1);
        row3.push_back(0);
    }
    game_grid.push_back(row1);
    hidden_grid.push_back(row2);
    guessed_grid.push_back(row3);       
}
std::cout << "Get ready, Challenger!" << std::endl << std::endl;
for(int a = 0; a < columns; ++a) {
  for(int b = 0; b < columns; ++b) {
  std::cout << game_grid[a][b] << " ";                                                                                                
  }
std::cout << std::endl;
}
}
```

I put the first vectors into the game_grid vector, and then called it inside a double for loop counting up to make a 6x6 grid and called game_grid from within that.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. You are awesome! This was a book problem, I was able to check with the solution after giving up. But I will try this too.